# If $A=\{R_1\le\frac{1}{2}\}$ and $B=\{R_2\le\frac{1}{2}\}$, find $P(A\cup B)$

Tags: probability, random-variables

> Let $(R_1, R_2)$ have the following density function
>
> $f_{12}(x,y)=\cases{
> 4xy  & \text{if } 0\le x,y\le1, x\ge y\cr
> 6x^2 & \text{if } 0\le x,y\le1, y>x
> }$
>
> If $A=\{R_1\le\frac{1}{2}\}$ and $B=\{R_2\le\frac{1}{2}\}$, find $P(A\cup B)$

First I found the individual density functions;

$\displaystyle f_1(x)=\int_0^x4xy\ dy+\int_x^16x^2dy=6x^2-4x^3$

$\displaystyle f_2(y)=\int_y^14xy\ dx+\int_0^y6x^2dx=2y$

then I thought,

$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$

$\displaystyle P(A)=P(\{R_1\le\frac{1}{2}\})=\int_0^{1/2}f_1(x)=2x^3-x^4\Bigg|_0^{1/2}=\frac{3}{16}$

$\displaystyle P(B)=P(\{R_2\le\frac{1}{2}\})=\int_0^{1/2}f_1(y)=y^2\Bigg|_0^{1/2}=\frac{1}{4}$

But what is $P(A\cap B)$, is it just the product, but also then the result would be false, $\displaystyle\frac{3}{16}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{3}{16}\cdot\frac{1}{4}=\frac{25}{64}$ (correct result is $\displaystyle\frac{3}{8}$)

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**:

The density is piecewise defined, if I integrate the first function; $\displaystyle\int_0^{1/2}\int_0^{1/2}4xy\ dxdy=\int_0^{1/2}\frac{y}{2}dy=\frac{1}{16}$

and this is exactly what I need for $P(A\cap B)$, but can somebody say, why I don't have to integrate the second function ($6x^2$) ?

Comment: There is no reason why P(A∩B) should be "just the product" since $R_1$ and $R_2$ are not independent.

Comment: $P(A\cap B) = P\{R_1 \leq \frac 12, R_2\leq \frac 12\} = F_{R_1,R_2}(\frac 12,\frac 12)$, where $F_{R_1,R_2}$ is the _joint CDF_ of $R_1$ and $R_2$.

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate how can I find it ? Is it $x^2y^2$ ?

Comment: Read your book; it should have a formula for the joint CDF in terms of the joint pdf. (Hint: the formula will have a double integral in it).  Apply the formula.